# Silly memory management issue that has me stumped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I have a property defined as:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITableView *settingsTableView;
```

Then in my **viewDidLoad** method I have:

```
self.settingsTableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:self.settingsTableView];
[self.settingsTableView release];
```

Then in the **dealloc** method of the view controller I have:

```
[settingsTableView release];
```

When I attempt to do the release from within the dealloc I am getting a "message sent to deallocated instance". I am starting to second guess myself, anybody see anything stupid in what I've done?

Really appreciate the help on this one!

Comment: BTW> No Interface Builder involved.

Comment: I recommend you read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html), it's a very good guide, it explains what autorelease is, when to use it, why you need it etc. If you have a C or C++ background, don't get fooled by the name, things are slightly different in Objective-C

Comment: Ok folks, thanks for all the assistance on this. I was very very influenced by this http://blog.thepete.net/2010/10/common-objective-c-memory-management.html

Comment: I must have misread what it was saying. The way I read it is. I initially alloc the UITableView which gets it a retain count of 1. I then set it to self.settingsTableView (which retains via a @property) so the retain count is 2. By using autorelease here, I get the retain count down to 1. I then add to the view's subview which retains it, so again I release. Now when the I want to dealloc, I just release and the retain count goes to 0 and it gets collected.

Comment: Light has gone on re: the release after the addSubview. I was overthinking things. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you're calling `release` on an object you've already `autorelease`d. Just get rid of the line

```
[self.settingsTableView release];
```

and you should be good.

Note that you *should* keep the release in the dealloc method, since the property calls retain for you, but not release.

Answer (score 4):

Two things. First, you're over-releasing the table view in the first place: the `autorelease` call negates the need for a manual `release` afterwards.

Also, in general, what you release in `-dealloc` are things that you created in `-init`, `-initWithCoder:`, or whatever, not `loadView` or `-viewDidLoad`. In this case, the method you're looking for is `-viewDidUnload`; you just have to set `self.settingsTableView` to `nil` in that method, and the property setter will handle releasing it if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the change you need to make.

```
self.settingsTableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:self.settingsTableView];
[self.settingsTableView release];
//^^^ This line is bad no need to release this value until dealloc
//if it is defined as retain or copy
```

Comment: Should he remove the "autorelease" too from the end of the first line?

Comment: Thanks Joe, I get it now. The *light* has just gone on.

Answer (score 1):

Seems obvious. You have already released with

```
[self.settingsTableView release];
```

So why release it again in the dealloc?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is related to your use of `autorelease` when you are allocating and initializing the UITableView.

You also might have a problem with releasing the settingsTableView right after you use it, vs. in the dealloc method.  Anytime you alloc/init an object, you should only release it once.

If you use autorelease, the rules are a little different, so I'd recommend reading up on that again.  Also, when you pass objects that you've created off to other things, they may take complete or shared ownership of the object by retaining it, meaning that you may or may not need to release it yourself anymore.  The documentation for that should be on the method you're calling (like `addSubView`).